Is there an expression for this specific part of a prime decomposition using only gcd,lcm,etc.?
Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with prime decompositions $$m = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{v_p(m)},\text{ } n = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{v_p(n)}.$$
It is well known that $$\text{gcd}(m,n) = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{\text{min}(v_p(m),v_p(n))}$$ and $$\text{lcm}(m,n) = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{\text{max}(v_p(m),v_p(n))}.$$ If one for some reason wants to have an expression for $$\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{\text{max}(v_p(m),v_p(n))-\text{min}(v_p(m),v_p(n))}$$ that does not mention the decompositions, they can achieve that since $\frac{\text{lcm}(m,n)}{\text{gcd}(m,n)}$ does the job.
My question now is: Is there such an expression for $$\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}, v_p(m) = v_p(n)} p^{v_p(m)}?$$

One expression is
$$\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}, v_p(m) = v_p(n)} p^{v_p(m)} = \frac{\gcd(m, n)}{\gcd\left(\gcd(m,n), \left(\frac{mn}{\gcd^2(m,n)}\right)^{\lfloor\log_{2}(\min(m, n))\rfloor}\right)} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
We have for any prime $p$ that
$$r_p = \nu_p\left(\frac{mn}{\gcd^2(m,n)}\right) = \nu_p(m) + \nu_p(n) - 2\min(\nu_p(m), \nu_p(n)) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
This shows $r_p = 0$ iff $\nu_p(m) = \nu_p(n)$. Thus, $\frac{mn}{\gcd^2(m,n)}$ contains only the prime factors $p$ of $m$ and/or $n$ where $\nu_p(m) \neq \nu_p(n)$. Thus, taking this to the power of $\lfloor\log_{2}(\min(m, n))\rfloor$ (note this will usually almost always be larger than necessary, but I used it as it always works, and I can't offhand think of any general expression to use which would be smaller & which doesn't involve dealing with the prime decompositions), as indicated in \eqref{eq1A}, means the exponents of those primes are greater than or equal to those in $\gcd(m, n)$. As such, taking the $\gcd$ of $\gcd(m, n)$ and this expression results in the value of $\gcd(m,n)$ with only those prime factors $p$ where $\nu_p(m) = \nu_p(n)$ being removed.
Finally, dividing this into $\gcd(m,n)$, as done in \eqref{eq1A}, results in just the prime factors $p$ where $\nu_p(m) = \nu_p(n)$. Since in those cases we have $\nu_p(m) = \nu_p(n) = \min(\nu_p(m), \nu_p(n)) = \nu_p(\gcd(m, n))$, we get that the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} is equal to the LHS.

Thank you for the great answer! One small question (or ask for confimation) however: Would you agree that the "mn" exponent (or even max(m,n), which can be used too I think) makes the right component in the denominator gcd so huge, that it makes the expression completely useless computationwise? I am not too familiar with computation complexity but it seems that even though Euclid's algorithm for the denominator should be easy after step 1, that first division with remainder will be a problem because of the size. And even computing the power is a problem in itself right?

@Hypatius You're welcome. I agree the exponent of $mn$ I used was very large. Since this was for an analytic solution, I didn't worry too much about its size. Nonetheless, you're correct $\max(m,n)$ can be used instead, but I've now updated my answer to instead use the considerably smaller, but still always applicable, $\max(\lceil\log_{2}m\rceil, \lceil\log_{2}n\rceil)$. This can also be relatively large but, depending on things like your programming language, libraries being used, etc., this may now be fairly doable computation-wise for a relatively large range of $m$ and $n$ values.

@Hypatius Note I realized I could make the exponent almost always being $1$ smaller by using $\max(\lfloor\log_{2}m\rfloor, \lfloor\log_{2}n\rfloor)$ instead. As such, I've updated my answer accordingly. If you think of any expression which always works and it doesn't involve the prime factor decompositions, but it's smaller, please let me know.

Hey John, thanks for the further input. I think one can even use min instead of max, right? Because of $\min{v_p(m),v_p(n)} \leq \lceil \log_2(\min{b,d}) \rceil$.

@Hypatius You're welcome. Also, thank you for your feedback. You're correct that I could have used a generally smaller value, i.e., $\lfloor\log_{2}(\min(m, n))\rfloor$ (I assume your $b$ and $d$ were meant to be $m$ and $n$ instead). I don't know exactly what I was thinking of when I used $\max$, but I believe it was something like the $\operatorname{lcm}$. Also, note that the floor function also works instead of the ceiling, although it's almost always only $1$ smaller. I've now updated my answer accordingly.

Exactly, I meant m and n, and not b and d.
